# Show that $(g \circ f)^{-1}$ is equal to $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$ as maps $\mathcal{P}(Z) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ be maps where the co-domain of $f$ is the domain of $g$; the composite map $g \circ f:X\rightarrow Z$ is thus defined.
Show that $(g \circ f)^{-1}$ is equal to $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$ as maps $\mathcal{P}(Z) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$.

We know that a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ can be viewed as a map from $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ to $\mathcal{P}(X)$ which can be further denoted by $f^{-1}$.

It's quite straightforward that $(g \circ f)^{-1}$ is define as $\mathcal{P}(Z) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$

$f^{-1}$ is defined as $Y\rightarrow X$ and $g^{-1}$ is defined as $Z\rightarrow Y$

Hence, $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$ is clearly $Z\rightarrow X$ which essentially is $\mathcal{P}(Z) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$

But is there a more rigorous proof? Because this seems rather obvious. a little TOO obvious if you ask me. Do i have to prove $Z\rightarrow X$ maps to $\mathcal{P}(Z) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$?

The inverse matrix product already gives this fact so i'm not sure if there is a more rigorous proof since it seems so trivial.

Comment: You need to show that $$(g \circ f)^{-1} (A) = f^{-1}(g^{-1}(A))$$ for any subset $A \in \mathcal{P}(Z) $. This is an equality of sets, you should prove it using double inclusion.

Comment: "$f^{-1}$ is defined as $Y\rightarrow X$" Do you mean that $f^{-1}$ is a map with domain $Y$ and codomain $X$? Only if $f$ is a bijection then $f^{-1}$ is used as notation for a map like that, and it denotes the so-called inverse of function $f$. In your question you are not dealing with inverses but with preimages under $f$. Also in that case notation $f^{-1}$ is practicized and it can be looked at as a function having $\wp(Y)$ as domain and $\wp(X)$ as codomain. Keep these concepts/notations strictly apart.

Comment: For the purposes of this question one should denote the induced map ${\cal P}(X)\to{\cal P}(Y)$ by $f^\wedge$ and the map ${\cal P}(Y)\to{\cal P}(X)$ (denoted by $f^{-1}$ here) by $f^\vee$.

Answer (score 2):

In general if $h:X\rightarrow Z$ denotes a map then every subset $C$ of $Z$ we has its preimage with respect to $h$ as a subset of $X$, notated as $h^{-1}(C)$ and defined as $\{x\in X\mid h(x)\in C\}$. So you could look at $h^{-1}$ as function $\wp(Z)\rightarrow\wp(X)$. This is the case in your question.

In that line: $$x\in h^{-1}(C)\iff h(x)\in C$$

So: $$x\in (g\circ f)^{-1}(C)\iff g(f(x))\in C\iff f(x)\in g^{-1}(C)\iff x\in f^{-1}(g^{-1}(C))$$

This proves that: $$(g\circ f)^{-1}(C)=f^{-1}(g^{-1}(C))=f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}(C)$$ This for every set $C\in\wp(Z)$, so we can say that: $$(g\circ f)^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$$